# AOSP 11 - Trying to make a rule, neverallow blocks successfull build

Tags: android, build, android-source, platform, selinux

I am trying to give access for three specific platform signed apps, I am able to allow some rules, but for one file access, it keeps saying in the build that some neverallow is blocking it. So, I googled up that I need to specify the rule just for those apps, because its now being too generic so the SELinux neverallow rule will prevent me to allow this kind of access for all platform apps. So, my question is - now I am trying to allow this: "allow platform_app sysfs:file { getattr open };", how can I "replace" the "platform_app" with something specific for those three apps, lets say for the start that I would like to try it on just one app? It works good with just the "getattr", but it denies the "open" paramater.

---build log---
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 1121 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 12579 of policy.conf) violated byallow platform_app sysfs:file { open };

So, how do I narrow down the "platform_app" to just my app? The previous adb logcat error looked like this (it is a different rule, now I am not able to access the device, but the error just stated "open" instead of "read"):

06-10 21:00:33.020  2022  2022 W DefaultDispatch: type=1400 audit(0.0:16): avc: denied { read } for name="devices" dev="sysfs" ino=8471 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.myapp.htgl

Comment: Which file do you want to open? you should label the file with a new label, then allow platform_app to open it.

Comment: Thanks @Yong, but I need to create a label (or service or whatever it takes) for the app, I need to access multiple files in /sys/devices...